# How do I parse an xml document as a stream using Scala?

Tags: xml, scala

How do I parse an xml document as a stream using Scala?
I've used the Stax API in java to accomplish this, but I'd like to know if there is a "scala" way to do this.

Comment: Does anyone know of a more complex / complete example than parsing "hello world"?

Comment: I knew of this thing because someone I once talked to was using it. What are you trying to do, and what problems are you having with it? Ask more questions. It will make it easier for the next person wanting to use it. :-)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use package scala.xml.pull. Snippet taken from the Scaladoc for Scala 2.8:

```
import scala.xml.pull._
import scala.io.Source
object reader {
  val src = Source.fromString("<hello><world/></hello>")
  val er = new XMLEventReader(src)
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    while (er.hasNext)
      Console.println(er.next)
  }
}
```

You can call `toIterator` or `toStream` on `er` to get a true `Iterator` or `Stream`.

And here's the 2.7 version, which is slightly different. However, testing it seems to indicate it doesn't detect the end of the stream, unlike in Scala 2.8.

```
import scala.xml.pull._
import scala.io.Source

object reader {
  val src = Source.fromString("<hello><world/></hello>")
  val er = new XMLEventReader().initialize(src)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    while (er.hasNext)
      Console.println(er.next)
  }
}
```

Comment: I had to change my code to val er = new XMLEventReader().initialize(src), but it looks like it's working. Thanks!

Comment: the 2.7 xml.pull is savagely borked and should be avoided entirely by all but the very brave. 2.8 situation is much improved.

Comment: scala.xml.pull is still really not great even now; I've proposed deprecating it: https://github.com/scala/scala-xml/issues/193

Answer (score -2):

```
scala.xml.XML.loadFile(fileName: String)
scala.xml.XML.load(url: URL)
scala.xml.XML.load(reader: Reader)
scala.xml.XML.load(stream: InputStream)
```

There are others...

Comment: Won't that load the entire document into memory? I'd like to parse it and handle it as I receive it and not store the entire document in memory first.

Comment: @ScArcher2: Yes, those are not streaming APIs.