# How do I parse xml into "messages" and print them out in scala using stream parsing?

Tags: xml, scala

Now that I know how to [parse xml in scala as a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908638/how-do-i-parse-an-xml-document-as-a-stream-using-scala/2909165#2909165) I need help understanding a non-trivial example.

I'd like to parse the following xml as a stream and send a message (print to console for this example) whenever I've parsed out a full message.

I understand that stream based parsing in scala uses case classes to handle the different elements, but I'm just getting started and I don't quite understand how to do this.

I have this working in java using a stax parser, and I'm trying to translate that into scala.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<messages>
<message>
   <to>john.doe@gmail.com</to>
   <from>jane.doe@gmail.com</from>
   <subject>Hi Nice</subject>
   <body>Hello this is a truly nice message!</body>
</message>
<message>
   <to>joe@gmail.com</to>
   <from>jane.doe@gmail.com</from>
   <subject>Hi Nice</subject>
   <body>Hello this is a truly nice message!</body>
</message>
</messages>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is for 2.8.

The typical way to process events is to use a match statement. In my case, i always had the need to store the parents as I process elements (to know for instance in what tag the text is located):

```
import scala.xml.pull._
import scala.io.Source
import scala.collection.mutable.Stack

val src = Source.fromString(xml)
val er = new XMLEventReader(src)
val stack = Stack[XMLEvent]()
def iprintln(s:String) = println((" " * stack.size) + s.trim)
while (er.hasNext) {
  er.next match {
    case x @ EvElemStart(_, label, _, _) =>
      stack push x
      iprintln("got <" + label + " ...>")
    case EvElemEnd(_, label) => 
      iprintln("got </" + label + ">")
      stack pop;
    case EvText(text) => 
      iprintln(text) 
    case EvEntityRef(entity) => 
      iprintln(entity) 
    case _ => // ignore everything else
  }
}
```

Because entity are events, you will probably need to convert to text and combine them with the surrounding text.

In the example above I only used label, but you can also use `EvElemStart(pre, label, attrs, scope)` to extract more stuff and you can add an `if` guard to match for complex conditions.

*Also if you're using 2.7.x, I don't know if http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2583 was back-ported so, you may have issues to process text with entities.*

More to the point, just dealing with from and to for brevity (though I would not call that the *Scala way*):

```
class Message() {
  var to:String = _
  var from:String = _
  override def toString(): String = 
    "from %s to %s".format(from, to)
}

var message:Message = _
var sb:StringBuilder = _

while (er.hasNext) {
  er.next match {
    case x @ EvElemStart(_, "message", _, _) =>
      message = new Message
    case x @ EvElemStart(_, label, _, _) if
        List("to", "from") contains label =>
      sb = new StringBuilder 
    case EvElemEnd(_, "to") => 
      message.to = sb.toString
    case EvElemEnd(_, "from") => 
      message.from = sb.toString
      sb = new StringBuilder 
    case EvElemEnd(_, "message") => 
      println(message)
    case EvText(text) if sb != null => 
      sb ++= text
    case EvEntityRef(entity) => 
      sb ++= unquote(entity) // todo
    case _ => // ignore everything else
  }
}
```

Comment: This is helpful, but still not quite what I'm looking for. I might be able to get something working using this.

Comment: I'm trying to discover the "scala" way to build out a "message" object, or possibly even just a tuple and then print that out all at once instead of just printing when i encounter each tag and text element.

Comment: Thank you for the example! This is exactly the information I was looking for. I am still interested in the "scala" way of doing it if there is a more functional way. Thanks again!