# efficient way of loading XML file in scala

Tags: scala, xml-parsing, scala-collections

What is the efficient way of loading `XML` file in Scala?
I do not want to load the complete file into memory as they can go upto 1 GB in my case, but read only required tags.
Let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use stream for this. check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908638/how-do-i-parse-an-xml-document-as-a-stream-using-scala

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse an xml document as a stream using Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908638/how-do-i-parse-an-xml-document-as-a-stream-using-scala)