# streaming an xml file in scala

Tags: xml, scala, playframework, streaming

I am working on a rest call using the play framework, slick in the dataBase and scala language and I want to return a response body as a stream (download file).
I have some data that I want to parse it in an xml file and send the response to the client as a stream.

Can someone help me how to proceed ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2908638/7803797

Comment: It is not so clear

Comment: possibly this can help you: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaStream

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse an xml document as a stream using Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908638/how-do-i-parse-an-xml-document-as-a-stream-using-scala)